# Output PHP into xml

Tags: php, xml

I'm working on my PHP as I want to get the list of links for each array in get-listing.php.

I want to get the list of links for each array like this:

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=ABC FAMILY&id=101
http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=CBS&id=102
http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=CNN USA&id=103
http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=ESPN USA&id=105
..and so on

I want to connect on each link in my PHP for each array to get the list of programme info to output them in the XML source.

Here's for e.g:

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php

I want to connect on get-listing.php and I want to connect on each link in the get-listing.php like cbs and cnn usa then I want to get access to get the programme info.

CBS programme info:

```
<span id="time1">12:00 PM </span> - <span id="title1">2014 NCAA Basketball Tournament"Dayton vs. Ohio State - LIVE</span><br><br>
<span id="time2">2:30 PM </span> - <span id="title2">2014 NCAA Basketball Tournament"Western Michigan vs. Syracuse - LIVE</span><br><br>
<span id="time3">5:00 PM </span> - <span id="title3">Local Programming</span><br><br>
<span id="time4">6:00 PM </span> - <span id="title4">Local Programming</span><br><br>
<span id="time5">7:00 PM </span> - <span id="title5">2014 NCAA Basketball Tournament"Wofford vs. Michigan - LIVE</span><br><br>
<span id="time6">9:30 PM</span> - <span id="title6">2014 NCAA Basketball Tournament"Arizona State vs. Texas - LIVE</span><br><br>
<span id="time7">12:00 AM </span> - <span id="title7"> 1 Local Programming</span><br><br>
<span id="time8">12:35 AM </span> - <span id="title8">Late Show With David LettermanTV-PG  </span><br><br>
<span id="time9">1:37 AM </span> - <span id=title9>The Late Late Show With Craig FergusonTV-14  </span><br><br>
```

CNN programme info:

```
<span id="time1">1:00 PM </span> - <span id="title1">Wolf</span><br><br>
<span id="time2">2:00 PM </span> - <span id="title2">CNN Newsroom</span><br><br>
<span id="time3">4:00 PM </span> - <span id="title3">The Lead With Jake Tapper</span><br><br>
<span id="time4">5:00 PM </span> - <span id="title4">The Situation Room</span><br><br>
<span id="time5">6:30 PM </span> - <span id="title5">Crossfire</span><br><br>
<span id="time6">7:00 PM </span> - <span id="title6">Erin Burnett OutFront</span><br><br>
<span id="time7">8:00 PM </span> - <span id="title7">Anderson Cooper 360</span><br><br>
<span id="time8">9:00 PM </span> - <span id="title8">Piers Morgan Live</span><br><br>
<span id="time9">10:00 PM </span> - <span id="title9">CNN Spotlight</span><br><br>
```

I want to get the list of programme info from each tag of `<span id="title1`, `<span id="title2`, `<span id="title3`...etc to allow me to generating for each xml tag `<programme channel="CHANNEL NAME" start="s1" stop="e1">`, `<programme channel="CHANNEL NAME" start="s2" stop="e2">` with each different start and end times then output the programe title in each xml tag called `<title lang="en">`.

The output for the XML would be looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tv generator-info-name="www.testbox.elementfx.com/xmltv">
<channel id="CBS">
   <display-name>CBS</display-name>
   <programme channel="CBS" start="s1" stop="e1">
       <title lang="en">2014 NCAA Basketball Tournament"Dayton vs. Ohio State - LIVE</title>
       <sub-title lang="en">sub title</sub-title>
       <desc lang="en">program description1</desc>
       <category lang="en">some category</category>
   </programme>
   <programme channel="CBS" start="s2" stop="e2">
       <title lang="en">2014 NCAA Basketball Tournament"Western Michigan vs. Syracuse - LIVE</title>
       <sub-title lang="en">sub title</sub-title>
       <desc lang="en">program description1</desc>
       <category lang="en">some category</category>
   </programme>
   <programme channel="CBS" start="s3" stop="e3">
       <title lang="en">Local Programming</title>
       <sub-title lang="en">sub title</sub-title>
       <desc lang="en">program description1</desc>
       <category lang="en">some category</category>
   </programme>
   <programme channel="CBS" start="s4" stop="e4">
       <title lang="en">Local Programming</title>
       <sub-title lang="en">sub title</sub-title>
       <desc lang="en">program description1</desc>
       <category lang="en">some category</category>
   </programme>
</channel> 

<channel id="CNN USA">
   <display-name>CNN USA</display-name>
   <programme channel="CNN USA" start="s1" stop="e1">
       <title lang="en">Wolf</title>
       <sub-title lang="en">sub title</sub-title>
       <desc lang="en">program description1</desc>
       <category lang="en">some category</category>
   </programme>
   <programme channel="CNN USA" start="s2" stop="e2">
       <title lang="en">CNN Newsroom</title>
       <sub-title lang="en">sub title</sub-title>
       <desc lang="en">program description1</desc>
       <category lang="en">some category</category>
   </programme>
   <programme channel="CNN USA" start="s3" stop="e3">
       <title lang="en">The Lead With Jake Tapper</title>
       <sub-title lang="en">sub title</sub-title>
       <desc lang="en">program description1</desc>
       <category lang="en">some category</category>
   </programme>
   <programme channel="CNN USA" start="s4" stop="e4">
       <title lang="en">The Situation Room</title>
       <sub-title lang="en">sub title</sub-title>
       <desc lang="en">program description1</desc>
       <category lang="en">some category</category>
   </programme>
</channel> 
</tv>
```

Here's the PHP script:

```
<?php

function db_connect()
{
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');

  $errmsg_arr = array();
  $errflag = false;
  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

  if(!$link) 
  {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$db) 
  {
    die("Unable to select database");
  }
}
db_connect();

  function clean($var)
  {
    return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($var));
  } 
  $channels = clean($_GET['channels']);
  $id = clean($_GET['id']);

  if($errflag) 
  {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    echo implode('<br />',$errmsg_arr);
  }
  else 
  {
    $insert = array();

    if(isset($_GET['channels'])) 
    {
      $insert[] = 'channels = \'' . clean($_GET['channels']) .'\'';
    }
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
    {
      $insert[] = 'id = \'' . clean($_GET['id']) . '\'';
    }

    if(!$channels && ! $id) 
    {
      $qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, links, streams FROM tvguide";
      $result1=mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());


      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
      {
        // fake some example data. the actual data would be retrieved from a database query
        $data[] = array('channel_id'=>$row['channels'],
        'display_name'=>$row['channels'],
        'program_id'=>123,'start'=>'s1','stop'=>'e1',
        'title'=>'program title',
         'sub_title'=>'sub title',
         'description'=>'program description1',
         'category'=>'some category');



        // build the xml    
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tv generator-info-name="www.testbox.elementfx.com/xmltv">';
        $last_channel = null; // used to detect when the channel changes
        foreach($data as $arr)
        {
            if($last_channel != $arr['channel_id'])
            {
                // the channel changed
                if($last_channel != null)
                {
                  // not the first channel, close out the previous channel
                  $xml .= "
</channel> \n";


                }
                // start a new channel
                $xml .= "
<channel id=\"{$arr['channel_id']}\">";
                $xml .= "
   <display-name>{$arr['display_name']}</display-name>";
                $last_channel = $arr['channel_id'];
            }
            // output the program info under each channel
            $xml .= "
   <programme channel=\"{$arr['channel_id']}\" start=\"{$arr['start']}\" stop=\"{$arr['stop']}\">";
            // i don't see a program id in this definition, but it likely needs one
            $xml .= "
       <title lang=\"en\">{$arr['title']}</title>";
            $xml .= "
       <sub-title lang=\"en\">{$arr['sub_title']}</sub-title>";
            $xml .= "
       <desc lang=\"en\">{$arr['description']}</desc>";
            $xml .= "
       <category lang=\"en\">{$arr['category']}</category>";
            $xml .= "
   </programme>";
        }
        if($last_channel != null)
        {
            // close out the previous channel if any
            $xml .= '
</channel>';
        }
     }

   }
   $xml .= '
</tv>';
   // output the xml to the browser in this example, write $xml to a file here...
   header("Content-Type: text/xml");
   echo $xml;
   $handle = fopen("myChannel.xml", "w"); 
   fwrite ($handle, $xml);
 }
?>
```

Can you please tell me how I can do that using with my php source?

Comment: There's a lot of code in this question, and it's not clear how much of your goal you have achieved and where you are stuck. Considering creating a smaller example which demonstrates the part you are having trouble with (for instance, we don't need to see your SQL code, only the data coming out of it). It may help if you structure your code into functions. Do make sure that the example runs and demonstrates the problem though. Producing the example may even reveal an obvious bug or solution to you.

Comment: @IMSoP Ok thats fair enough,. Can you tell me how I can open the url in get-listing.php to get the url in each array to retrieve the data and output it using with "$xml .= "<programme channel=\"{$arr['channel_id']}\" start=\"{$arr['start']}\" stop=\"{$arr['stop']}\">";??